# Qt on Windows - unrecognized command line option

Tags: windows, qt

I installed Qt Creator 5.0.1 (I have Windows 7) and tried to compile a simple "Hello, World" project. It failed with a comment "unrecognized command line option -fno-keep-inline-dllexport" Any ideas, how this can be corrected or what I did wrong?

Comment: What compiler are you using? From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Creator) it seems you can use one of two, and the command line argument seems to be available in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: Qt Creator 5.0.1? That is not released yet. It should be Qt 5.0.1. Whatever, would you please post some codes or the contents of *.pro file or Makefile?